# How to find a picture header in transport stream?

Tags: video, transport-stream

If picture header is codec dependent or there is some general location where we can find picture header in transport stream ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is Start Codes Extraction.

If you have a raw Transport Stream with MPEG-2 video:

1. Look for packets which have the PayloadUnitStartIndicator bit set in the TS header, this indicates the start of a PES packet.
2. You need to look at the 4th byte of such PES packet to determine the **StreamId**. The PES Start Code looks like this

   0x00 0x00 0x01 0xXY

The PES Start Code for a packet with a Picture header is

```
0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00
```

For H.264 I believe you would be interested in packets which have the Sequence Parameter Set (SPS) and/or the Picture Parameter Set (PPS) NAL units instead of the picture header.